# How to troubleshoot multiple apps on Mountain Lion all missing toolbar icons?

Tags: macos, finder, safari, preview

My machine awoke from sleep, and third party apps as well as Finder, Preview and Safari's toolbar only shows the blank buttons similar to the image below.

After restart the machine, the problem persists. I also tried using Disk Utility to verify / fix the permissions on the Apple installed software to no avail.

How can I troubleshoot or fix this?

[image]

Comment: That's not finder. Are you using a third party finder replacement?

Comment: It's TotalFinder isn't it ?

Comment: Ya, the screen is TotalFinder.  But both Safari and Preview have the same problem. If I kill the TotalFinder and go back the original Finder, all the toolbar buttons are still blank.  However, if I create another account, all are normal without problem.

Comment: I would make a backup and re-run the combination installer [(10.8.2 currently)](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1581) to be sure you are not missing some system frameworks / code to handle toolbar rendering.

Comment: Thanks, @bmike.  I had done the same as u advised.  But still have no idea what's the reason.  From Leopard till Mountain Lion, never got such issue, only after 10.8.2 and on rMBP.

Comment: I have seen this just happened to my rMBP, but this has been on 10.8.2 since it came out, and happened to me 2 days ago. Creating a new account shows clearly something in ~/Library has to be the culprit... I've also removed all startup items and using lingon to disable my various launchdaemons. Using Onyx doesn't help fix this either.

Answer (score 4):

Reboot in safe mode (hold Shift on start), login to your account and restart. I don't know what's the reason for icons disappearing but the above fixes it.